# If an element $a \in A$ is an upper bound for $A$, then $a = \sup A$.

Tags: real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Prove that if an element $a \in A$ is an upper bound for $A$, then $a = \sup A$.

To prove this, do I need two cases and follow the definitions of the infimum and supremum?

Comment: You need to prove that if $b>a$, then $b$ is not the supremum (since there is not an element of $A$ arbitrarily close to $b$) and if $b<a$, then $b$ is not the supremum (because there is an element of $A$ greater than $b$).

Comment: Please title your questions in a more descriptive way than "Problem 2."

Comment: Let $a \in A$ be an upper bound. Suppose there exists some $b$ such at $b$ is the supremum of $A$ And use @MichaelBurr comment. That is, show that $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** To show $a$ is the supremum of $A$, you need to show two things:

- $a$ is an upper bound for $A$. (Given.)
- If $b$ is any upper bound for $A$, then $b \ge a$. (For this part use the fact that $a \in A$.)

Comment: So first part I can assume what is going on and what's already been given and the second part I can follow from the definition of the supremum?

Comment: @Tim Yes. $\;\;$